# Terraform outputs 'Error: Variables not allowed' when passing list variable by command line

Tags: command-line, terraform, var

My variable.tf file is

```
variable "users"{
    type = list
}
```

My output-list.tf file is,

```
output print-users{
    value = "First user is ${var.users[0]}\nSecond user is ${var.users[1]}"
}
```

When I do **terraform plan** and provide input as ["Abhishek","Arya"] it gives output as expected.
[image]

But when I do **terraform plan -var 'users=["Abhishek","Arya"]'** it gives following error,
[image]

Maybe I'm doing silly mistake but can't find it, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you : )

Comment: First, please make sure you post errors as text, not screenshots. Second, it seems a lot of details are missing. Are you using modules? If not, where is this variable supposed to be used? Is it only for the purpose of creating an output?

Comment: Its not possible to get such an error based on what you described. Like MarkoE wrote, your question probably lacks crucial information.

Comment: This message suggests that your shell is passing the argument to Terraform as if you had written `[Abhishek,Arya]` without the quotes, which makes Terraform think you are trying to refer to variables named `Abhishek` or `Arya`. However, if you are on a Linux/Unix system then the command line you shared should be correct because the `'` single quotes mean to take the contents literally. Are you working on a Windows system? The argument quoting conventions are different on Windows.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, sorry kind of new using stackoverflow to ask question , I'll keep in mind for future questions : )
To answer your other question, No I'm not using modules or anything advanced, simple two files mentioned in question & yes, variable is just for purpose of creating output. 

Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

`terraform plan -var "users=[\"Abhishek\",\"Arya\"]"` this one works. So basically  it's the difference in ways windows understands characters.

[terraform-plan-passing-value-for-list-variable-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380652/terraform-plan-passing-value-for-list-variable-on-windows)

Thank you @martin-atkins